# Can we plan serverless aws instead of deploying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, serverless

We can plan terraform before applying the deployment, similarly do we have something in serverless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `serverless package` to create the CloudFormation json files.
The files will be created under the `.serverless` directory.

Comment: Is it going to compile and provide me the errors if any?

Comment: `cat <yourCFNtemplate> | xargs -0 aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body` will validate the template:
https://dev.to/amezousan/how-to-validate-cloudformation-templates-31ml